# Is Ada suitable for game development?

Tags: opengl

Would Ada be a practical language for game development (at least for the PC--I understand there aren't compilers for PlayStation and other consoles)?

It has bindings to OpenGL, it has decent performance, and it's less error-prone than C++. Please feel encouraged to support your point with relevant example projects you know about.

Comment: "less-error prone than C++" is a little subjective...

Comment: @Byte56 I really don't think it is. Ada is built to be deterministic with a meticulously detailed spec contracted by the department of defense and used throughout the aerospace industry because it's much harder to make mistakes than with other industrial languages. I'm pretty sure there have been studies to support the notion that debug time is reduced in Ada, but I don't care to look for them at the moment.

Comment: I see. Do you work in development for Ada? Is this question some sort of promotion for Ada?

Comment: @Byte56 Nope. I used it in a college course and realized it seems to have many advantages over C++, so I would like to know if it would be suitable for game development.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Ada folks make bank in the defense/aerospace industries... I don't think they're too interested in courting the game industry. And if they were, I don't think they would have someone asking lame questions on a Q/A board; they'd probably develop a proof of concept and market it more traditionally. ;)

Comment: Practical for one person if 1) a compiler exists and 2) you're the only one working on it and you're happy with Ada.  I dare you to try and find a second person to develop a game with using Ada, however =)  This is just like Erlang server tech, it's neat and all that but finding anyone competent to work on it is nearly impossible.

Comment: @PatrickHughes I understand. Although a talented developer should be able to grasp Ada in a week or so--I think the issue is simply finding talented developers (a task that is challenging irrespective of language).

Comment: Without knowing anything about the specifics of Ada I would say that anything that was designed for scientific/engineering purposes will have accuracy at its core (at the expense of speed). Whereas a good game engine has believable accuracy with high speed

Comment: @RichardTingle As best I can tell Ada is not particularly slow. It of course depends on compiler and compiler settings, but a few quick Google results show no signs of inherent speed bumps in the Ada language: http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~adagroup/sigada-website/lawlis.html http://www.ada-deutschland.de/sites/default/files/tagungen/2003/COMPEXETIME_EADS.pdf

Comment: With unpopular languages, finding developers that can work with you in those languages is not the big problem, it's the lack of an ecosystem - 3rd party libraries, knowledge base, tool support. Suddenly you find that you have to solve 100 more problems that aren't problems with popular languages. For an example of this, look at [D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)) which, as a language, is superior to C++ in every way, except popularity.

Comment: @congusbongus +1 Yeah, and I'm absolutely expecting this. I'm fairly unversed with Ada, but I understand it has the ability to bind to C and (I think) C++ libs. Out of curiosity, what are some kinds of libs that most/all games (OpenGL, for example)?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @RichardTingle All the benchmarks I've seen show Ada competing with C and C++ (depending on compiler/settings, of course).

Comment: @weberc2 Fair enough, as I say its my uninformed gut feeling. Also I now note this is a complete language rather than a library which does change matters (I'd expect a science/engineering library to focus on accuracy, a complete language on the other hand wouldnt have to make that choice)

Comment: On one of the answers below you comment "I'm much more interested in it for the novelty." If you're mostly interested in it for the novelty, then why do you even care if it's suitable? Questions like this are a waste of time that clutter up the site.

Comment: @jhocking Why would it matter _why_ I'm interested? Had I not said I was interested in the novelty (in a comment), you wouldn't have had any problem with the question, but because I'm interested in it for novelty it automatically becomes invalid and unhelpful for others? Moreover, in what world are does a novel interest preclude curiosity as to the suitability of a particular tool? I don't understand your reasoning at all. lol.

Comment: I already voted to close before I saw that comment (ie. I already thought this was a bad question) but seeing that comment changed my reaction from just "huh another bad question" to "grr this guy annoys me." The reason matters because this site is for *practical* questions that actually *address a problem you have*; if you already know that this isn't a practical question then that's even worse than if you naively posted without realizing that.

Comment: btw I'm not just making up that reason. Here's the "Asking" help page for this site http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @jhocking It _is_ a problem I have. I'm researching languages to start an exploratory project. It's purely for my own personal use, but it's a _problem_ that _I face_ nonetheless. Moreover, this question is neither chatty nor open-ended. It's a very practical question even if my project is experimental in nature. It is truly sad that some of these Stack Exchange communities trend toward such a conservative interpretation of these guidelines--it's this narrow-minded view that diminishes the usefulness of this site, IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. But it depends entirely on the game you want to make, and how much time you want to spend making it.

Clearly, Ada is not a well known language in the world of game development. That comes with it a few complications:

- You'll have to create most of your own tools/libraries (pathfinding, texture/model parsers, animation libraries, etc.)
- I don't think any game engines exist using Ada, so you'll first be making an engine (not a game) (graphics engines for Ada *do* exist, so at least you'll have a start...)

**These tasks will take you a long time. Likely longer than any theoretical gains from Ada being "less error-prone" to develop in.** Given the limitations, I'd say it's viable for game development, but not practical. At this point, I think the only reason to develop a game in Ada is for the novelty of developing a game in Ada.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, I'm much more interested in it for the novelty. I expect it will be hard, but I like experimenting with new technologies. Good answer, +1.

Comment: If you're mostly interested in it for the novelty, then why do you even care if it's suitable?

Comment: @weberc2 Where by 'new' you mean 'only 30 years old'?  If you're interested in experimenting with new or even new-to-you technology then Ada is almost certainly the exactly _wrong_ direction to be going; aside from intellectual curiosity (which is not to be underestimated but can be satisfied in other ways), I can see no fundamental benefits to learning to develop games in Ada over, e.g. Ruby or Haskell or Lua or heaven-forbid C++ or...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You're right, I should have said "new applications of technology". Ada seems more promising for game development than Ruby, Haskell, and Lua which (afaik) are non-optimal. Furthermore, in many ways, it is a better language than C++ (a conversation not worth getting into here as programmers are prone to confusing criticisms of programming languages and personal attacks). In short, I want to explore to find a better way of developing games without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 1):

The commercial game 'Strategic Command' was written in Eiffel. You can write a the game logic in just about any language, the challenge lies in the GUI and IO parts. Your ADA environment should have capable libraries.

Btw there is an Ada version for .net but with serious limitations due to the constraints of the platform.